# Onclick Image open/popup file field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a File Field in my Form. That field looks so odd. So i want to make it an Image. So that i click on Image and it opens a file field(Choose a file).

Give me the Best solution. For All Browsers Support.

Comment: The whole idea of StackOverflow is for people to give the "best" solution. that's why we have votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do :

HTML Code

```
<label class="filebutton">
Browse For File!
<span><input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"></span>
</label>
```

CSS Styles

```
label.filebutton {
    width:120px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

label span input {
    z-index: 999;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -700px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    cursor: pointer;
    _cursor: hand;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the field transparent and place it inside a div with overflow:hidden and your image as background:

```
<div style="width:16px;height:16px;overflow:hidden">
  <input type="file" name="file" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)">
</div>
```

If the image is bigger than default size of the field you will also have to write JS which moves field according to cursor position so try to avoid that.